# Why the timer setTimeout returns the first value "2"

Tags: javascript, settimeout

below the code. It should write down to console numbers from 0 to 19. Actually it does. But what is the first number it has print in console?

```
var i = 0;

var timerId = setInterval(function () {
    console.log(i++);
}, 100);

setTimeout(function() {
    clearTimeout(timerId)
}, 2100);
```

Comment: Unclear what you're asking... The code works as expected, prints 0-19

Answer (score 0):

Although your code works as expected, it could be that under some conditions you wouldn't print all numbers. It might be better to check the counter value and then clear the interval at that time (timing in javascript is not really that precise as you might hope it to be)

You could try to do it like this though, to make sure that your interval can only run once, and that you don't exceed your max value.

```js
function Counter(start, maxValue, ticks) {
  this.value = start || 0;
  this.max = maxValue;
  this.ticks = ticks;
  var interval;
  
  this.stop = function() {
    if (!interval) {
      return;
    }
    clearInterval(interval);
    console.log('stopped counter');
  };
  
  this.increase = function() {
    this.value++;
    console.log(this.value);
    if (this.value >= this.max) {
      this.stop();
    }
  };
  
  this.start = function() {
    if (interval) {
      return;
    }
    console.log('starting counter');
    interval = setInterval(this.increase.bind(this), this.ticks || 0);
  };
}

var counter = new Counter(0, 20, 100);
counter.start();
```

Answer (score -1):

From `setInterval` documentation

> Calls a function or executes a code snippet repeatedly, with a fixed time delay between each call to that function. Returns an intervalID.

Comment: @ste2425 setInterval returns the id out so it get printed. that's what the OP ask about right? (the strange number aside those from 0-20)

Comment: It does not get printed as he is not logging the intervalId, or at least not from the code OP's included. So going from what the OP has included this bears no relevance. EDIT: I deleted my original comment by mistake, thought it was a different post.

Comment: @ste2425 i think OP tried it in Dev Tools. It does get printed in Dev Tools

Comment: You are correct and if that is what the OP is referring to i apologize. Maybe you should add that however to your answer so other people and the OP realize that's what you mean, gives your answer some context. Also what your describing happens because the `setTimeout` is not being passed to a variable so it prints the `intervalId` for the `setTimeout` not `setInterval`.

Comment: Tuan Anh Tran thanks. That's what I wanted to know.
Sorry for unclear explanation.